# A systemd service won't run for an app

Tags: linux, systemd, ruby

I want to create systemd for "RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rake jobs:work"

I have this:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/systemd/system/my_bg_jobs.service 

[Unit]
Description=bg jobs
After=syslog.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=my_user123
WorkingDirectory=/home/my_user123/projects/ruby/my_app123
ExecStart=/home/my_user123/.gem/ruby/2.3.4/bin/bundle exec rake jobs:work
Restart=on-abort
Environment=RAILS_ENV=staging
SyslogIdentifier=my_bg_jobs

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I'm running it:

```
  $ sudo systemctl status my_bg_jobs
    ●   
       Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/my_bg_jobs.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
       Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-07-10 11:07:29 +07; 1s ago
       Process: 24138 ExecStart=/home/my_user123/.gem/ruby/2.3.4/bin/bundle exec rake jobs:work (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
       Main PID: 24138 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)


      [..........]

     systemd[1]: Started bg jobs.
     my_bg_jobs[24138]: /home/my_user123/.rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:241:in `bin_path': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNot>
     my_bg_jobs[24138]:         from /home/my_user123/.gem/ruby/2.3.4/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'

     systemd[1]: my_bg_jobs.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
     systemd[1]: my_bg_jobs.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Why is that and how to fix it?

I have bundler in place:

```
$ which bundler

/home/my_user123/.gem/ruby/2.3.4/bin/bundle
```

The rake job itself, without systemd, when run normally, runs flawlessly.

Comment: This is very old, but did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

There is something missing in your environment. Certainly the PATH entry for `/home/my_user123/.gem/ruby/2.3.4/bin`, and maybe other variables.

Try starting your application with `env -i`. You can then add the necessary environment variables to the env command line and to the systemd unit file, or you can create a shell script that sets up the environment and then calls the command you want to execute.